# glDrawPixels isn't filling the window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm using GLFW on MacOS and I'm using some OpenGL calls to draw an image in the window. For some reason, glDrawPixels(...) isn't filling the window. This is what I have:

```
#define IMAGE_WIDTH     800
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT    600

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    int nx = IMAGE_WIDTH;
    int ny = IMAGE_HEIGHT;

    // One time during setup.
    unsigned int data[ny][nx][3];
    for( size_t y = 0; y < ny; ++y )
    {
        for( size_t x = 0; x < nx; ++x )
        {
            data[y][x][0] = ( rand() % 256 ) * 256 * 256 * 256;
            data[y][x][1] = 0;
            data[y][x][2] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(nx, ny, "FOO", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawPixels( nx, ny, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data );

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to make it as clear as possible. The window dimensions and the pixel data should be based off the same provided dimensions, so it's a little unclear to me why it seems to only fill a quarter of the screen. Here is a screencap of the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVfY8.jpg

Comment: Seeing a screenshot might be helpful. Could it have to do with a high-DPI display?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/4kbFzij

Comment: The screenshot you posted is 1600x1200, and the covered area is 800x600. You seem to have some DPI issues.

Comment: Okay, let me see research that angle.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672935/why-retina-screen-coordinate-value-is-twice-the-value-of-pixel-value FWIW, it works fine on Windows. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja I think yours is the right answer. How can I flag it as the answer?