# Why does the same code work differently on a laptop monitor and an external monitor

Tags: c++, opengl, hardware, ssao

I am using the SSAO code from [learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=advanced-lighting/ssao), but there are different results between my laptop monitor(***LM***) and external monitor(***EM***).

EM result(Good):

[image: External monitor result]

LM result(Bad):

[image: Laptop monitor result]

And when I drag the result window from LM to EM, the window doesn't change, vice versa.

Also, I use

```
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

to set viewport size[[reason]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672935/why-retina-screen-coordinate-value-is-twice-the-value-of-pixel-value), and I got

- EM : screenWidth = 800, screenHeight = 600 **(equal to window size)**
- LM : screenWidth = 1600, screenHeight = 1200

While I set laptop monitor viewport size to (800, 600), the result is good:
[viewport size (800*600) LM result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8xAN.png)

When I don't use SSAO or do some simple tasks(skybox, loading model, etc), the result is same.

My laptop monitor is:

```
Retina 13.3-inch(2560 x 1600)
Intel Iris 1536 MB Graphics Card
```

My external monitor is:

```
AOC 2489W1 23.5-inch(1920 x 1080)
Intel Iris 1536 MB Graphics Card
60Hz
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, I only use one graphics card on my mac(Intel Iris 1536 MB). And I use HDMI to connect my laptop and the external monitor.

Comment: Do you use the same viewport size on both monitors? Could the problem be related to the size of some render-buffers?

Comment: The viewport size is different on both monitors, I used `glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);` to set viewport size. I think the problem may be related to some SSAO render-buffers, but I don't know how to debug such this problem.

Comment: @heyanbai In general the SSAO algorithm needs to know the resolution of the source textures (respectively the viewport size). Do yous set the proper viewport size?

Comment: I use the viewport size by which the result can fill the window. When I use the viewport size (800 * 600) for the laptop monitor, the result is same as the external monitor, but only displayed in the bottom left corner of the window.